# How do directives communicate by a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In this document: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, it says directives may communicate with each other by controllers.

> **controller** - Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other directives if they request it by name (see require attribute). **This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior.**

I don't understand it well, how they communicated with controllers? Is there any example or demo for it?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915332/what-does-require-of-directive-definition-object-take) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/GSZkJ/).

Comment: Keep up with good questions.

Comment: [that example](http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/GSZkJ/)  is a bit misleading. at first glance it appears to be sharing the controller instances' 'num' property. when the only thing that's actually happening is the inner directive is copying the increment function from the outer directives controller instance to the scope object which both inner and outer share. when it's called from the template this == the scope object.  see this [tweaked example](http://jsfiddle.net/fess/a68Ra/) which tries to illustrate those points.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Perhaps you're confusing a controller that is created when a route change occur with a directive controller. That section is only talking about directive controllers, so what that section means is that if you have two directives on the same HTML element, they can communicate by requiring each others controllers.

A good example of that is if your creating a directive that needs to communicate with `ng-model`. Since `ng-model` exposes a controller, you can require it like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            // Here you can listen to different DOM events, and
            // call ngModelCtrl when the model value needs to update
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" my-directive>
```

Your directive can expose a controller by implementing it in the object that your directive function returns, like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective1', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

        },
        controller: function() {
            this.sayHello = function() {
                alert("hello!");
            }
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective2', function() {
    return {
        require: 'myDirective1',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs, myDirective1Ctrl) {
            myDirective1Ctrl.sayHello();
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="text" my-directive2 my-directive1>
```

You can also require a directive controller from a parent directive by writing `require: '^myParentDirective'`, like this:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective1', function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

        },
        controller: function() {
            this.sayHello = function() {
                alert("hello!");
            }
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective2', function() {
    return {
        require: '^myDirective1',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs, myDirective1Ctrl) {
            myDirective1Ctrl.sayHello();
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div my-directive1>
    <div my-directive2></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only prooves how f... convoluted is the current angular docs. They just don't care.

Comment: @AndersEkdahl You mention that this works for two directives on the same element, and also for child and parent elements, but does it work for sibling elements? I've seen examples of this done, but I've never been able to get it work myself. I always get an error of 'such and such' directive does not have 'such and such' controller.

Comment: @Nocturno only works for nested Directives, not sibling. You can though, you can use an intermediate Directive to communicate.